# What's wrong with my C++ solution?

Tags: c++, recursion

**Here is the problem description:**

> Write a function that counts how many different ways you can make
>   change for an amount of money, given an array of coin denominations.
>   For example, there are 3 ways to give change for 4 if you have coins
>   with denomination 1 and 2:
>
> 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 2+2.
>
> The order of coins does not matter:
>
> 1+1+2 == 2+1+1
>
> Also, assume that you have an infinite amount of coins.
>
> Your function should take an amount to change and an array of unique
>   denominations for the coins:
>
> count_change(4, [1,2]) # => 3
>
> count_change(10, [5,2,3]) # => 4
>
> count_change(11, [5,7]) # => 0

I have written a C++ implementation for the problem, However, for some test cases that didn't get the right answer. For example, the output of `count_change(10, {5, 2, 3})` is 2 whereas the expected output is 4. I haven't figured out what's wrong with my program, who can point out the disadvantage of my solution?

**Here is my solution below, and I tried to solve the problem by the use of recursion:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int count_change(int money, vector<int>& coins)
{
  int count = 0;
  if(coins.size() == 1){
     if(money % coins[0] == 0)return 1;
     else return 0;
  }
  int last = coins[coins.size()-1];     
  coins.pop_back();
  for(int i = 0; i < money/last; i++)
      count += count_change(money-i*last, coins);
  return count;
}

 int main()
 {
   vector<int> coins = {5, 2, 3};
   cout<<count_change(10, coins)<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 3):

You pass your vector by reference.

Each recursive call (in the loop!) will do its own `pop_back`, altering the vector, though they should work on the same list of numbers.

Pass by value.

Comment: Thank you, passing by value really solves the problem, but could you please be more specific? I need to pop back the last element of original vector, it seems passing by reference is a good choice, actually I don't quite understand what's wrong with it?

Comment: If you don't get it, it's time to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the problem space in half. Is the problem with your algorithm or your implementation? Start by writing down your algorithm. Then execute your algorithm on paper for the case where you get the wrong answers and see if the algorithm gets the right answers.

If the algorithm gets the wrong answers, then the algorithm is broken. You have a non-programming issue.

If the algorithm gets the right answers, then your implementation is broken. You can now use either a debugger or additional logging to see where the implementation differs from the work you did on paper.

Comment: This looks like a comment to me.

Comment: He didn't ask a specific, answerable question. This is probably about the best answer that can be given to what he did ask. (Teaching a man how to fish is a better answer to "why don't I have any fish" than giving him a fish.)

Comment: No, this a suggestion for a generic method for bug hunting. Write a blog article or post a community question and link to that in the comments. If you don't like the question you also could have asked for clarification. Based on your reasoning, you could copy-paste this answer to half the questions on SO, which is clearly nonsense. I understand you're frustrated that beginners don't know some basic reasoning methods to solve problems, but this is not the way to go.

Comment: It's not generic, it's specific to his problem. It's clear from his question that his issue is that he doesn't know whether the issue is with his algorithm or its implementation, that's what he's stuck on. The next step in solving the problem is figuring out which.